# Centering a header in latex

Tags: sectioning, headline

I have the following command,

```
\def\thesection{\Roman{section}}
```

but I need to center it, put it in normal font, and add point (.) to the heading. Currently it is something like:

**I Introduction**

What I want is something like

I. INTRODUCTION 
(NTRODUCTION) should appear smaller in size than the I, and should as well be centered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I think the task is a bit complicated, as I am trying to change a template from the CVPR'19 [http://cvpr2019.thecvf.com/] conference to align with the ICDAR'19 [https://icdar2019.org/]. That said, every template has its own userpackages, .sty and other related files. I thought of saving time by tweaking the CVPR'19 doc to the ICDAR'19. Seems a bit difficult task.

Comment: Do you really want to modify a template designed for a conference?

Answer (score 1):

Based on report's chapter, I made a redefinition of section.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\def\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\secdef\@section\@ssection}
\def\@section[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \fi
    \sectionmark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makesectionhead{#2}]%
    \else
    \@makesectionhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
    \fi}
\def\@makesectionhead#1{%
    \vskip -3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex%
    {\centering \normalfont\bfseries
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        {\huge\thesection.}\space{\Large #1}\par\nobreak
        \fi
        \vskip 2.3ex \@plus.2ex
}}
\def\@ssection#1{\if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makessectionhead{#1}]%
    \else
    \@makessectionhead{#1}%
    \@afterheading
    \fi}
\def\@makessectionhead#1{%
    \vskip -3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex%
    {\centering \normalfont\bfseries{\Large #1}\par\nobreak
        \vskip 2.3ex \@plus.2ex
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

---

### Edit

Modify only the definition of `\thesection`.
**This is not a good option** as depicted below.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\def\thesection{\normalfont\Roman{section}.}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

    See \cref{sec:intro} or \emph{with emphasis \cref{sec:intro} vs. I.}. And adding the point leads to two consecutive dots at the end of previous phrase (ugly).
    I you want to put the ref in bold: {\bfseries \cref{sec:intro} vs. I.}, it doesn't work too.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The code is auseom, however, it did not work well when I embeded it to the template.

Now, is there a simple way to add just a point to this command?
`\def\thesection{\Roman{section}}`   ............
I Introudction to  I. Introduction

Comment: What doesn't “work well”? Sure: `\def\thesection{\Roman{section}.}` But this point will appear each time you'll call `\thesection`

Comment: Perfect. Indeed, I need this. Now, can I add something to  enforce 
 `\def\thesection{\Roman{section}.}` to normal font, instead of it being bold font?

Comment: This is not a good option, since you enforce `\normalfont` for every call of `\thesection`. See the edit.